# how to migrate website to framework?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a website currently hosted. I created barely without using any frameworks and also without following any convictions because of which am facing lot of difficulty in maintaining the site. During the course of time i learned yii framework and now am capable of creating a web application from the scratch using yii.

Now my question is:

1. Do i need to remodel my site from the scratch ?
2. can i use any of the code that i currently have with me or i need to rewrite them ?

My study:

In various forums and writings i found that if i have designed my current site with oops principles and followed the patterns i could. But unfortunately as i said above during development i was not fully aware of problems like this, so i missed them.

Am looking for good suggestions on how to achieve my goal and directions to any good research or results which might save my time.

tech details about my website :
PHP for server-side, mysql for datastore and all other html5, css3, jquery and js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, you would have to think about what models and controllers you need
- Then make the yii project from scratch
- Then see how you can use the existing code, and where it would go.
- The biggest task would probably be putting the html code in the correct views.
- The CSS/JS part will remain most likely the same.